# mysql_db_query for mssql in php

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

What is mssql function that have similar with mysql_db_query()?

and what about mysql_insert_id()?

Comment: ops, sorry for not inform about language, it's php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [PHP Mssql documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php). The functions you're looking for are [`mssql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) and the following:

```
<?php 
function mssql_insert_id() { 
    $id = 0; 
    $res = mssql_query("SELECT @@identity AS id"); 
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        $id = $row["id"]; 
    } 
    return $id; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: For mysql, it has mysql_query and mysql_db_query, but for mssql only has mssql_query. mssql_query same with mysql_query but not with mysql_db_query.

Comment: @Hafizul `mysql_db_query()` is deprecated, all it does is (effectively) `mysql_select_db()` followed by `mysql_query()`. You can easily emulate this behaviour with `mssql_select_db()` and `mssql_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you will come to this in T-SQL is the following:

```
Use <MyDatabase>
Exec ('Select <ColumnList> From <SomeTable>')
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL, you can use the **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** function to get the last ID created by the given connection, in the same scope. Put them both together so you get the ID back just after row creation.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field1,field2) VALUES(val1,val2); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS myId;
```

Note, you could also use **@@IDENTITY**, but that returns the last ID created, regardless of scope, so if you inserted a new row, and a trigger/stored procedure fired and inserted something into another table, @@IDENTITY would return that ID.